Autodesk events not being triggered on iPad
We have an issue with Autodesk viewer when on Safari on iPad. We have event listeners in Javascript attached to Autodesk.Viewing events (specifically Autodesk.Viewing.OBJECT_TREE_CREATED_EVENT), which are fired on desktop, but not iPad.
The event listeners are added in JS (and the code to add is being run) as follows:
viewer.addEventListener(
    Autodesk.Viewing.OBJECT_TREE_CREATED_EVENT,
    handlerToCall
);

I have tested by connecting an iPad (9th gen, iPadOS 18.0.1), attached to Web Inspector on Macbook. I added Event breakpoints for the Autodesk.Viewing.X events, but they are never hit (other non-Autodesk breakpoints are hit e.g. DOMContentLoaded), so that rules out general events not being hit.
I know that there are other ways of reacting to events - but would prefer not to have to use a different method if possible (e.g. https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/wait-events-viewer)

Thank you for the heads up! Let me pass the info to the viewer team, and report back here when I get their feedback.

I've just tested a simple viewing app on my iPad (7th generation, iPadOS 17.5.1), and the events are triggered fine. I'll try the newer iPadOS version as well but I'm not sure that's the root cause.
Can you try the following sample on your side? Just fill in your own ACCESS_TOKEN and DESIGN_URN:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/style.css">
</head>

<body style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">
    <div id="preview" style="position:absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 50%;"></div>
    <div id="events" style="position:absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 50%; padding: 1em; box-sizing: border-box; overflow-y: scroll;"></div>
    <script src="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/viewer3D.js"></script>
    <script>
        const ACCESS_TOKEN = "";
        const DESIGN_URN = "";

        Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer({ env: "AutodeskProduction", accessToken: ACCESS_TOKEN }, function () {
            const viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D(document.getElementById("preview"));
            viewer.start();
            viewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.OBJECT_TREE_CREATED_EVENT, () => log("Object tree created"));
            viewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT, () => log("Geometry loaded"));
            viewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT, () => log("Selection changed"));
            Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load(
                "urn:" + DESIGN_URN,
                (doc) => viewer.loadDocumentNode(doc, doc.getRoot().getDefaultGeometry()),
                (code, message) => console.error(code, message)
            );
        });

        function log(message) {
            const events = document.getElementById("events");
            const log = document.createElement("p");
            log.innerText = `[${new Date().toISOString()}] ${message}`;
            events.appendChild(log);
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>



Thanks for getting back to me!
I've used your code on our side and we're seeing the events as you've shown.
However, when I add the event logs in our code, either we're not getting the models loading, or sometimes the object tree event is not firing. This is on iPad.
I fear that we've got some extensions, or set up that is not behaving.
Now that I know that the iPad is capable, we'll have to audit our code to see if there is anything causing issues on our side.
I'll report back if we learn anything!

Turns out the problem we were having was not related to events at all - so apologies for the red herring. It was due to mis-configured loading of the MemoryLimited extension. It was being used without a memory limit specification, which seemed to cause big issues!
